# Investments with constant change of residence around the world

Tags: investing, tax-residency

Let's suppose I have a given amount of money that I desire to invest for a long-term goal, e.g. 15-20 years, and that my job makes me change residency in several parts of the world, i.e. during this period I could move my residency within Europe, UK, USA and Asia.

Where should I invest the money so that I could keep it in the same 'spot' without continuously changing the provider due to my residence changes?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have anything you consider your "Home-country" i.e. where you plan to retire or where your relatives live?

Comment: yes I do, maybe it is in Europe. why is this relevant?

Comment: You may want to Base your Capital in a Jurisdiction you know well and plan to use in the future? Also some things may require your personal presence, so it´s nice if you are there for Christmas anyways and you can stop by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to maintain residency in a country to keep a bank account there.  Investments are no different.

Unless you plan on investing in property (which some countries require citizenship/residency for) it really doesn't matter where you reside.

Answer (score 2):

You have the opportunity to invest anywhere. Developed markets (US, Europe, Japan, etc) generally provide less risk on average compared to emerging markets.

Your residency doesn't impact your ability to invest anywhere or in any certain type of security. However, it might be wise to invest in the currency or country that you plan on eventually living. By doing that, you will remove currency risk for when you actually need the money.

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere? I mean, seriously, choose a country that looks stable for you, choose a bank in it, done. My brokers do not care where I reside (letter with new address, done), my fund provider does not etc.

Comment: right..but Robo-Advisors don't let you reside everywhere...

Comment: But this question is about investments. Not robo advisors.

Comment: Vanguard, Wealthfront, Betterment, TD Ameritrade, Charles Schwab and many others have  robo advisors.  It may be a rumor but I've heard that they handle investments.